# Receiving and setting an Obj-C mutable pointer in a Swift function

Tags: objective-c, macos, swift

I am trying to provide an OS X service, but I am not sure how to translate the following Objective C documentation example to Swift. Any pointers (forgive the pan) would be appreciated!

From Apple's documentation (section 'Implementing the Service Method'):

```
- (void)simpleEncrypt:(NSPasteboard *)pboard userData:(NSString *)userData error:(NSString **)error {
    //...
}
```

Is this the equivalent in Swift?

```
func simpleEncrypt(pboard: NSPasteboard!, userData: String?, error: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<String?>) {
    //...
}
```

Or should it be:

```
func simpleEncrypt(pboard: NSPasteboard, userData: String, inout error: String?) {
    //...
}
```

Or indeed something entirely different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upon more careful reading of the documentation:

```
import AppKit

@objc public class Servicer: NSObject {

    @objc public func service(pboard: NSPasteboard?, userData: String?, error: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSString?>) {
        error.memory = "Not yet implemented!"
    }
}
```

This is ported to obj-c in "Servicer-Swift.h" as:

```
SWIFT_CLASS("_TtC8Servicer8Servicer")
@interface Servicer : NSObject
- (void)service:(NSPasteboard *)pboard userData:(NSString *)userData error:(NSString * *)error;
- (instancetype)init OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
@end
```

**pboard** can probably be an implicitly unwrapped optional (**NSPasteboard!**) or even a plain reference (**NSPasteboard**), because it is very unlikely that the os will call this method with a nil pasteboard...